# echoing content from another funtion php script

Tags: php

Hi I need help about echoing message from another function, below is my script, in my database is already set the product_quantity is 0, but not able show the alert message, its that anything wrong in the code?

```
function get_products_in_cat_page(){
    $query = query(" SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_category_id = " . escape_string($_GET['id']) . "  ");
    confirm($query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0) {
        set_message("Will update soon the new products");
    } else {
        while($row = fetch_array($query)) {
            $product_image = display_image($row['product_s_image']);
            $outofstock = out_of_stock();   //--this is alert message I echoing from another function like below --//
            $product = <<<DELIMETER
                <div class="product clearfix">
            <div class="product-image">
            <a href="product.php?id={$row['product_id']}"><img src="../resources/{$product_image}" alt="{$row['product_title']}" class="selected"></a>
            {$outofstock}
            </div>
            <div class="product-desc center">
            <a href="product.php?id={$row['product_id']}">
            <div class="product-title"><h3>{$row['product_title']}</h3></div>
            </a>
            <div class="product-price">${$row['product_price']}</div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
DELIMETER;
            echo $product;
        } 
    }
}

function out_of_stock(){
    $query = query(" SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = " . escape_string($_GET['id']) .  " ");
    confirm($query);
    while($row = fetch_array($query)) {
        if($row['product_quantity'] < 1) {
            echo "<div class='out-of-stock'>Out of Stock</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never mind help with echoing a message, I think you need help with indenting! Couple side notes, I would maybe think about using a prepared statement instead of stuff like this `" SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_category_id = " . escape_string($_GET['id']) . "  "` Also, what does the `query()` function look like? There are some unknowns to this question...

Answer (score 0):

`out_of_stock()` needs to return the string so that the variable assignment will work, instead of echoing it.

```
function out_of_stock(){
    $result = '';
    $query = query(" SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = " . escape_string($_GET['id']) .  " ");
    confirm($query);
    while($row = fetch_array($query)) {
        if($row['product_quantity'] < 1) {
            $result .= "<div class='out-of-stock'>Out of Stock</div>";
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Also, if `product_id` is the primary key of the `products` table, you don't need a loop here. You can also put the quantity check into the SQL.

```
function out_of_stock(){
    $query = query(" SELECT 1 FROM products 
            WHERE product_id = " . escape_string($_GET['id']) .  
            " AND product_quantity = 0");
    confirm($query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1) {
        return "<div class='out-of-stock'>Out of Stock</div>";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

It also seems strange to perform a separate query for this, when you already have `$row['product_quantity']` available in the loop in `get_products_in_cat_page()`.

```
    while($row = fetch_array($query)) {
        $product_image = display_image($row['product_s_image']);
        if ($row['product_quantity'] < 1) {
            $outofstock = "<div class='out-of-stock'>Out of Stock</div>";
        } else {
            $outofstock = "";
        }
        $product = <<<DELIMETER
            <div class="product clearfix">
        <div class="product-image">
        <a href="product.php?id={$row['product_id']}"><img src="../resources/{$product_image}" alt="{$row['product_title']}" class="selected"></a>
        {$outofstock}
        </div>
        <div class="product-desc center">
        <a href="product.php?id={$row['product_id']}">
        <div class="product-title"><h3>{$row['product_title']}</h3></div>
        </a>
        <div class="product-price">${$row['product_price']}</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
DELIMETER;
        echo $product;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, could you show me how to combine together in get_products_in_cat_page() ? instead of separate query.

Comment: You're using `SELECT *` in the first query. So the information is already in `$row['product_quantity']` in the main loop. Just use `if ($row['product_quantiy'] < 1)` and add the alert there.

Comment: Hi Barmar, could you able please show me the example?

Comment: I've added it to the answer